# How to change section style using sciposter

Tags: sciposter, posters

I am trying to get rid of the default "boxedsections" with shadows used in the sciposter class and replace them with either "plainboxedsections" or "plainsections".

In the manual three heading options are mentioned, but not how to switch between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation indicates that these are class options. So I suggest you try

```
\documentclass[plainsections]{sciposter}
```

or

```
\documentclass[plainboxedsections]{sciposter}
```